# What is the name of the 65537-gon?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, terminology, plane-geometry, polygons

I know the name of the [heptadecagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptadecagon) (17 sides) and the [diacosipentacontaheptagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/257-gon) (257 sides). But what is the name of the [polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65537-gon) with 65537 sides? I am unable to figure it.

Comment: The modern Greek for $65537$ is  εξήντα πέντε χιλιάδες πεντακόσια τριάντα επτά so perhaps that might give you a clue

Comment: "Gobbledygookon"

Comment: You could call it the Hermes polygon, after the fellow who constructed it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Gustav_Hermes

Comment: @Henry So you're telling us that it's a hexentapentechiliadepentacositriantaheptagon?

Comment: Mightaswellbenaninfinity-gon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the portuguese nomenclature (I am from Brazil) and translating to english its results:

hexacontakaipentachiliakaipentahectakaitriacontakaiheptagon.

Best regards!!

Comment: "kai" means "and" so I think we need a single one at the end. So hexacontapentachiliapentahectatriacontakaiheptagon?

Answer (score 39):

"$65537$-gon" **is** the name.  Likewise "$257$-gon": 
writing (let alone saying) something like "diacosipentacontaheptagon"
serves less to communicate $-$ if indeed it succeeds in communicating at all $-$
than to show off.

Comment: Indeed. :) .....

Comment: Let me thank user-14830 for his constructive answer.

Comment: @coudy think of translating 14830 into Greek as well.